# Use Regex to get string from HTML tag attribute - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am very new to Regex but I think it is the best way to do this. I really need to get the text from an HTML tag attribute to an array of strings to be able to work with. I have multiple `<span>` tags with an onclick attribute. It's the text from within the attribute that I need. I will give you an example.

```
<span class="ord" onclick="top.wiki_ord_klick('abstrakt','icke konkret, ogripbar')">abstrakt</span><br>
```

This is a span class with an onclick attribute. What I want to access is the words in top.wiki_ord_klick(...). I want them to be individually made strings and put into an array. The result would be

```
var result = ["abstrakt", "icke konkret, ogripbar"];
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience! I ment it like two strings, icke konkret and ogripbar should be only one string. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following uses [**match()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with regular expression `/'.+?'/`.  This matches everything between single quotes (including the quotes), and this returns the parameters as an array.

It then iterates through the array using [**map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to remove the single quotes.

```js
var span = document.querySelector('span.ord'),  //get the <span> element
    click = span.onclick.toString(),            //get its inline click event as a string
    parms = click.match(/'.+?'/g);              //get an array of the onclick parameters

parms = parms.map(function(parm) {
  return parm.replace(/'/g, '');                //remove single quotes
});

console.log(parms);
```

```html
<span class="ord" onclick="top.wiki_ord_klick('abstrakt', 'icke konkret, ogripbar')">abstrakt</span>
```